# Never prompted for password when installing LAMP server

Tags: debian, raspbian, lamp, apt-get

I was following a tutorial on how to set up a LAMP Server on a Raspberry Pi but I got different results than the tutorial.

When installing MySQL using:

`apt-get install mysql-server php-mysql -y`

I was never prompted to provide a password. Afterwards, when installing phpMyAdmin, using:

`apt-get install phpmyadmin -y`

Again, I was not prompted to provide a password.

Then, of course, it came time to login to phpMyAdmin, but I did not have any password to use.... I have been working through a number of online tutorials to reset my MySQL password but None of them have worked. Furthermore, it appears that I have MariaDB instead of MySQL--so I tried some tutorials to reset that password, again, nothing.

Then, I tried reinstalling MySQL completely, but again, I was not prompted for a password.

Is there a way I can just force the terminal to prompt me for a password when reinstalling? That seems like it would be the easiest way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to figure out which server you're running — 'mysql-server' is a metapackage that in turn depends on another package, such as 'mysql-server-5.7'. There are a couple of ways you could do that, but I suggest `dpkg -l | grep server|grep database`

That will give a list of results such as:

> ii  mariadb-server                   10.1.26-0+deb9u1               all          MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
>
> ii  mariadb-server-10.1              10.1.26-0+deb9u1               i386         MariaDB database server binaries
>
> ii  mariadb-server-core-10.1         10.1.26-0+deb9u1               i386         MariaDB database core server files
>
> rc  mysql-server-5.5                 5.5.57-0+deb8u1                i386         MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

This is on my current Debian system and shows that I have the 'mariadb-server-10.1' server installed, which was selected by the 'mariadb-server' metapackage. I used to have 'mysql-server-5.5' installed but the 'rc' shows that it's been removed. You may instead see something like 'mysql-server-5.7'.

From there, you can reconfigure the package (either as root or with sudo): `dpkg-reconfigure -plow mysql-server-5.7`. That will tell Apt to reconfigure without removing your existing databases or configuration.

The reason it didn't ask you the first time is very likely the `-y` flag, which attempts to run non-interactively. I can't guess the expected behavior of Apt in this situation or what password it might have selected.

phpMyAdmin doesn't set a password, it just passes along your credentials to MySQL/MariaDB, so you'll never be prompted to set a password when installing phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try force to set mysql password?

`mysql -u root -p`

If this not work and you are in "apt-distro" try to completelly remove mysql with:

`sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean`

and then install it again.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, at least not when it came time to login through phpMyAdmin as root.

Comment: Try after close session or restart.

Comment: I just did--still refuses to let me sign in via phpMyAdmin. Is it possible that I am only changing MySQL Password and not the MariaDB Password?